# Should I create a reference field or a third content type to represent a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: 8

I have a student table and a course table that have a many-to-many relationship (a student can take many courses, and a course can be taken by many students).

If I am implementing the above data model as a database, I would create a third table to represent the many-to-many relationship.

But I want to implement the above data model in Drupal 8. I think that in Drupal 8 there are two ways to implement the above data model:

- I can create a reference field in one of the two content types
  (student or course) that points to the other content type.
- I can create a third content type that have two reference fields
  that points to the student and course content types.

Am I correct that these two ways are valid? And if I am correct, which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

I know you won't like this answer but in general **it depends**:

What are your use cases when adding a new relationship? Is it more likely to add classes via students or the other way around? Or is it a migration process?

If **UI** is heavily used by both of the entites, I would give reference fields to both content types, and always update the other type reference field upon saving one type.

If this is more like for **listing** stuff (without editing on the UI these properties) and the information is coming from a big relationship list, then I would store it in a key-value table or a custom table.